# Does gcc 4.7.3 on cygwin support C++11 concurrency features?

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin

I am trying to compile the following program on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine with cygwin installed and
the gcc compiler updated to 4.7.3:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

std::mutex flemutex;
std::mutex arrmutex;

main() {

thread t;
}
```

On compiling with the following command:

```
 gcc -std=c++11 -o file.o -c file.cpp
```

I get the following errors:

```
file.cpp:12:1: error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
file.cpp:13:1: error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:39:3: error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’
file.cpp:39:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t’
```

Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Did you try to add `-lpthread` to gcc's command-line ? (2) You can download MinGW, that doesn't need cygwin and works with threads "from the box"

Comment: I did try adding -lpthread to the command line, and it did not work. Anyway, I'm just compiling here, not linking, so that should not have any effect, right? Also, I'm hoping this works on cygwin and do not have to install MinGW on my machine. Can both co-exist peacefully on the same machine?

Comment: Simple - update cygwin and gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

main() {
#ifndef(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS)
  cout << "GThreads are not supported..." << endl;
#endif
}
```

In fact, as of GCC 4.4, `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` is undefined when `libstdc++` is built because Cygwin implementation of `pthread` lacks some functionality. The same was true for MinGW.

**NOTE:** GThreads, which is directly used by `std::thread`, is a GCC wrapper around POSIX threads.

There are **[builds of MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)** based on GCC 4.7 and 4.8 targeting both 64-bit and 32-bit, which offer experimental support for `std::thread`. Furthermore, yes, of course Cygwin and MinGW can co-exist as long as you switch between these 2 environments correctly, i.e. do **not** mix them in the `PATH` environment variable.

Relevant links:

- **[Thoughts on supporting the C++11 thread library on Windows](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-05/msg00020.html)**;
- **[GCC 4.4.0 - Can't activate threading support](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/GCC-4-4-0-Can-t-activate-threading-support-td50226.html)**;
- **[New Rubenvb GCC 4.8 std::thread enabled build](http://www.mail-archive.com/mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06982.html)**.